# Including a specific module in rollup build

Tags: javascript, rollup, rollupjs, umd

I'm using Rollup to build a UMD version of my module.

This `rollup.config.js` successfully builds my module, without including `@tensorflow/tfjs`:

```
import path from 'path';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';

export default {
  input: "dist/tmp/index.js",
  output: {
    file: "dist/umd/index.js",
    format: 'umd',
    name: 'Foo',
    globals: {
      '@tensorflow/tfjs': 'tf',
    }
  },
  context: 'window',
  external: ['@tensorflow/tfjs'],
}
```

However, I rely on a second module (`tensor-as-base64`) that I *do* want to include in the bundle. I cannot figure out how to include that specific module.

From a lot of googling it seems like I need to use `@rollup/plugin-commonjs` and `@rollup/plugin-node-resolve`, but I can't find any examples for how to scope the includes to a specific folder under `node_modules`. I've tried something like this:

```
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';

export default {
  input: "dist/tmp/index.js",
  output: {
    file: "dist/umd/index.js",
    format: 'umd',
    name: 'Foo',
    globals: {
      '@tensorflow/tfjs': 'tf',
    }
  },
  context: 'window',
  external: ['@tensorflow/tfjs'],
  plugins: [
    nodeResolve({
    }),
    commonjs({
      include: [/tensor-as-base64/],
      namedExports: {
        'tensor-as-base64': ['tensorAsBase64'],
      },
    }),
  ]
};
```

This seems to just hang with no output.

Any tips on how to include a single specific module from the `node_modules` folder (and ignore everything else in that folder)?

**Update 1**

I tried this config:

```
export default {
  input: "dist/tmp/index.js",
  output: {
    file: "dist/umd/index.js",
    format: 'umd',
    name: 'Foo',
    globals: {
      '@tensorflow/tfjs': 'tf',
    }
  },
  context: 'window',
  external: ['@tensorflow/tfjs'],
  plugins: [
    nodeResolve({
      resolveOnly: [
        /^(?!.*(@tensorflow\/tfjs))/,
      ],
    }),
  ],
})
```

This produces the following output:

```
dist/tmp/index.js → dist/umd/index.js...
[!] Error: 'default' is not exported by ../../node_modules/tensor-as-base64/dist/index.js, imported by dist/tmp/upscale.js
```

Which is accurate in that `tensor-as-base64` does not export `default`.

After including the commonjs plugin, it gets into an infinite loop. I *think* that's where I'm missing some bit of configuration.

I should add that this is a monorepo, so maybe there's an issue with `node_modules` being at the root of the folder?